# Chromium not updating transform-origin

Tags: css, reactjs, chromium, css-transforms, styled-components

When using React to render a spinner in Chromium-based browsers, the `transform-origin` property only updates after either of the following:

- The viewport is resized
- I use my mouse to hover anywhere inside the developer tools

The spinner is built using `styled-components` with the `keyframes` helper, but since it works in Safari & Firefox, I'm not too sure it's a React issue after all.

Refer to the following GIF (apologies for the potato quality):

[image: Sorry for potato quality]

All other browsers produce the expected result immediately. Is this a known Chromium bug? Am I missing something here?

**Edit:**

Here's the Spinner element. It is the only thing being rendered from the App's entrypoint.

```
import React from "react";
import styled, { keyframes } from "styled-components";
import { COLOR_PRIMARY } from "core/constants";

const SpinnerWrapper = styled.div`
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: ${props => props.size || "2rem"};
    height: ${props => props.size || "2rem"};
    pointer-events: none;
`;

const spinnerAnimation = keyframes`
    from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
`;

const SpinnerItem = styled.div`
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: calc(100% - 12px);
    height: calc(100% - 12px);
    margin: 6px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: ${spinnerAnimation} 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1) infinite;
    border-color: ${props => props.inverse ? "white" : COLOR_PRIMARY} transparent transparent transparent;
    animation-delay: ${props => props.delay || "0"}s;
    transform-origin: 50% 50% !important;
`;

export default ({ size, inverse }) => (
    <SpinnerWrapper size={size}>
        <SpinnerItem inverse={inverse} delay={-.45} />
        <SpinnerItem inverse={inverse} delay={-.3} />
        <SpinnerItem inverse={inverse} delay={-.15} />
    </SpinnerWrapper>
);
```

Comment: Could you provide some code for testing?

Comment: @cbdev420 I have added my example code. Running the same code in CodeSandbox does not reproduce the result, which leads me to further believe that this is a Chromium issue after all. CodeSandbox internals might work differently and therefore work

Comment: this might be a bug because i have a similar issue. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56731024/javascript-to-load-content-in-html-sometimes-unless-element-hovered-inside-inspe)

Answer (score 1):

Without some example code demonstrating your problem, it is difficult to know if I am solving your actual issue or not, but I managed to get in a similar situation.

On [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gpv6bhqs/) which approximately reproduces your animation, the transform-origin is changed to center when the mouse hovers the body, however on some browsers (can confirm current Chrome and Chromium 75) the value won't update while the animation is running unless, as you mentioned, the element gets inspected.

A possible trick that I have found is to reset the animation. You can do that by duplicating your keyframes declaration and switch to the alternate one when changing the transform origin:

```
@keyframes spin {
    from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { transform: rotate(1turn); }
}
@keyframes spin2 {
    from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { transform: rotate(1turn); }
}
.part {
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    animation: spin 1.5s ease infinite;
}
body:hover .part {
    transform-origin: center;
    animation-name: spin2;
}
```

Here is [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zfj56Lrg/) showing the trick.

If you don't want to duplicate your keyframes, I believe you could also use JS to remove the animation, force a reflow then add it again. Example:

```
// Removes the animation
myElement.style.animation = 'none';
// Forces a reflow - the browser will register that the animation was removed
myElement.clientWidth;
// Adds the animation back (resets it to what is defined in the CSS)
myElement.style.animation = '';
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, however the transform origin in my case is set initially and never changed. Any ideas?

Comment: @NikxDa I am unsure why this happens to you. Maybe the component gets mounted reusing another one with a transform-origin, you could try adding a `key` on your element. Another solution is to embrace the fact that the origin is top left. Change things to `transform-origin: 0 0;` and change the transforms in your keyframes to `transform: translate(50%, 50%) rotate(...) translate(-50%, -50%);`