# Javascript to load content in HTML sometimes unless element hovered inside inspect

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made a widget. The content of this is loaded dynamically by JS.
However, sometimes when a page loads the data does not show up on the widget unless it is clicked upon. Even going into inspect and hovering over any element loads the items. The two images below are before and after click.

**Update 1**- Click doesn't necessarily loads the data but hovering inside inspect element does.

**Update 2** - This seem to get fixed if I call the function to put data multiple times. Note: I have 15 sec timer to call the function, however if I reduce the interval of first 4 runs, it fixes. However, this seems like a workaround and not a solution.

**Update 3** - As Suggested, this appears more of a css issue
Created a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sc0rp1on/4bfvcun3/)

[image: Before click/hover] [image: After Click/Hover]

Here is the function that  is putting the data

```
function putData(dataSet) {
if(dataSet.length == 3) {
    document.getElementById('liveBlock').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('upcomingCompletedBlock').style.display = 'block';
    for(var i=1; i<=3; i++) {
        title = dataSet[i-1].title;
        teams = title.split(' vs ');
        homeTeamName = teams[0];
        awayTeamName = teams[1];
        homeTeam = dataSet[i-1].homeTeamLogoUrl;
        awayTeam = dataSet[i-1].awayTeamLogoUrl;
        document.getElementById('botCupLogo'+i+'1').src=homeTeam;
        document.getElementById('botCupLogo'+i+'2').src=awayTeam;
        document.getElementById('botCupName'+i+'1').innerHTML=homeTeamName;
        document.getElementById('botCupName'+i+'2').innerHTML=awayTeamName;

        if(dataSet[i-1].matchStatus == 'UPCOMING') {
            var date = new Date(dataSet[i-1].startDateTime);
            document.getElementById('summaryText'+i).innerHTML = date;
        }
        else if(dataSet[i-1].matchStatus == 'COMPLETED') {
            document.getElementById('summaryText'+i).innerHTML = dataSet[i-1].summaryText;
        }
    }
}
```

It is called by a different function which fetches data from an API. The data is correctly fetched and passed into this function

Comment: Check an confirm if required elements are loaded before the function called.

Comment: Where is the function `putData` executed ?

Comment: @SandeshJain Yes, because if they hadn't, the function would log an error about not being able to set property of null

Comment: @CharlieH, it is executed through another function which fetches data from API. That function is executed after DOM is loaded

Comment: Where does dataSet come from? Do you expect dataSet.length to equal 3 on page load?

Comment: @MichaelvE As mentioned above, dataSet is sent from another function which fetches the data from an API and yes dataSet is of length 3. The problem shouldnt be with it

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint or a console.log at the first line of this function?
And i would also try debugging a separate listener for the same element.

Comment: @tomitheninja Yes I have. Every function runs successfully

Comment: Are you using hot reloading?

Comment: @NikxDa I'm not sure what you are referring to as I am using vanilla JS but I am replacing html content via JS

Comment: `putData` should be correctly asynchronously called after the code that generates your original box thing.

Comment: That looks sort of 3D to me.  How are you rendering your widget?  Is there a CSS animation or is it a Three.js cube or something?  How do you draw the widget?  It seems like maybe the widget isn't redrawing correctly.  But you haven't shown any of your widget code.  Maybe add a snippet to this question that reproduces the problem, or at least shows how you draw the widget?

Comment: If you can replicate your problem is a JSFiddle, I'm sure someone will understand it better and offer a concrete solution.

Comment: @Wyck Thank you for the suggestion. This does appear to be css issue. I have created a fiddle

Comment: I am able to reproduce your issue but only in Chrome.  It does not reproduce in Edge, for example.  It may be a CSS bug based on the fact that the element is zero area when it updates, but then transitions to be a non-zero size.  I haven't delved into the Chromium source, but it's really looking like a browser bug.  You can work around by updating the element's innerHTML when the transition begins.

Answer (score 0):

> I have made a widget. The content of this is loaded dynamically by JS.

Do you mean you add the HTML content by JS? I bet that there is a coordination issue. Maybe the function that adds this content, call it `createContent`, fires one or more times after your `putData` function, and overwrites the DOM elements to their initial values. Or maybe `putData` fires early and the elements are not loaded.

> This seem to get fixed if I call the function to put data multiple times.

Which supports the coordination issue hypothesis.

**Advices**

- Wrap your `putData` function content in a `try catch`. It will prevent your JS from crash and will help you to debugging.

  Since you are manipulating DOM elements that could not be loaded or targeted. Something like this:

```
function putData(dataSet) {
    try {
        // add your code here
        return true;
    } catch (reason) {
        console.error(reason); // <-- pay attention to the console
        return false;
    }
}
```

- Do not call the `putData` multiple times ramdomly. Instead, call it when the HTML content is ready.

  For example, at the end of `createContent` you can call the function that fetches the data and then `putData` with its response. Another option is to use a custom event and dispatch it at the end of `createContent`.
- Inside the proposed function `createContent`, check if content is alreadty loaded. And if `isLoaded`, do not load it again.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Nico, but this doesn't help.
1. The initial content is not loaded by JS but HTML which gets overwritten by JS. Now, if the new content was overwritten it would have been persistent. However, if I check the content, it shows the new content. There is no error thrown by the JS and function runs fine(debugged)

Answer (score -1):

Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/zqxa0fL8/

What I had to do is to remove the unnecessary `perspective(1200px)` from all CSS rules except `mybot .cube`

The red side still has an issue, as it's CSS differs from the other sides. Should be fine after you do a refactoring.

Too much CSS stuff in your code. Try minimize the code only to what is needed.

**UPDATE:**

See: https://jsfiddle.net/8u24pyeq/
Turns out the issue is because of `backface-visibility`.
You need to wait before page renders and only then apply the setting.

Comment: While I agree that .innerHTML for non-HTML strings is a bad practice, I don't think this answer solves OP's problem.

Comment: I have tried this already. This doesn't help.
InnerHTML is bad practice because it might cause XSS attacks and is 10x slower but it basically does the same job.

Comment: @user11658885 I have stripped the CSS and made back similar to other. Issue still persists [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sc0rp1on/3dxj62wu/16/)

Comment: @user11658885 I can confirm that, this change does reduces the number of times the problem happens but doesn't resolve it